# Deploying to Azure not running EF Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am running Entity Framework with Code First Migrations. My new release adds a table, modifies a few tables, and run some scripts. This works perfectly when developing locally using update-database.

Upon deployment the new table was not created and I was receiving errors from my client. I attached the debugger to the deployed site to track through what was happening. It reached the controller, went through the normal flow, and upon hitting the first database call to the new (but not actually existing yet) table it hopped into the Configuration class for my migration.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<myProject.api.AuthContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\Auth";
        ContextKey = "myProject.api.AuthContext";
    }
```

So I'm thinking great, all should be well. It goes through all of these, returns to the initial database call, but then that call returns an error, pasted below

> The model backing the 'AuthContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

This is surprising since indeed I have enabled code first migrations! Using the standard enable-migrations and add-migration, which work perfectly on my local machine when I issue the update-database command.

1) How can I get my Code First migrations to run once deployed to Azure?

**Update 1**

Here are my publish settings. For some reason I do not have the checkbox option for: "Execute Code First Migrations" and am guessing that's the issue...
[image]

Comment: Which DatabaseInitializer are you using? Should look something like: Database.SetInitializer<AuthContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Configuration>())

Comment: ```public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ...
    }
```
tells entity framework that you don't want it to run migrations automatically, only when you specifically use the package manager console command ```Update-Database```

I have the opposite issue. I just connected to a new db on Azure and automatic migrations ran *despite* my config specifying ```AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huzzah! My update was the issue. I found from other SO posts that his happens sometimes. A Clean and Rebuild, followed by restarting VS, restored the 'Execute Code First Migrations' checkbox. Re-deployed and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Had the same problem, but the above did not do the trick. The following did. In global.asax I have "Database.SetInitializer(new xxxDbInitializer());" I commented out this line, rebuild, commented in, rebuild and the checkbox run code-first migrations reapeared. Unfortunatly a new problem occured. Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'xxx' in table 'xxx' is specified more than once. I'll open a new question for this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked these lines of code?

In your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

In your global.asax.cs / Startup.cs (OWIN startup):

```
var configuration = new Migrations.Configuration();
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
```